# Is it possible to inject global scope into instantiated class in ES6 aka singleton?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

First of all I need to apologize because this is going to have alot of code in it, which will bloat this question. However I think this will help to understand my problem a little better.

Let's say I have this given `MainModule`:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Loads Module from given name.
 * @class {LoadModules}
 */
class LoadModules {

  constructor(moduleName) {
    // define Modulename.
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
  }

  /**
   * Initialize module.
   * @method init
   * @return {void} [nothing]
   */
  init() {

    // Path Module.
    const path = require('path');

    // Require Module from given Name.
    let ModuleToLoad = require(path.join(__dirname, 'Modules', this.moduleName, this.moduleName + '.js'));
    // Instatiate Module.
    ModuleToLoad = new ModuleToLoad();
    // Start module.
    ModuleToLoad.init();
  }

}
```

And an other module which can be loaded into the `MainModule`:

```
/**
 * This is a Module which can be loaded by the MainModule.
 * @class {ModuleToBeLoaded}
 */
module.exports = class ModuleToBeLoaded {

  constructor() {
    /**
     * Empty
     */
  }

  /**
   * Initialize newly loaded Module.
   * @method init
   * @return {void} [nothing]
   */
  init() {
    console.log('module Loaded');
  }

};
```

As you can see this is used to load modules dynamically, which works perfectly fine.

My problem is that my `MainModule` which loads other modules dynamically can't share its own global scope between the modules, or at least I didn't figure out how. I am well aware that this is complicated since my `MainModule` and `ModuleToBeLoaded` are in different files.

For example I have a `LoggerClass` in my global scope of my `MainModule`:

```
// This is in the global scope.
const LoggerClass = new Logger();
/**
* LoadModule class stuff comes after this.
*/
```

I want all Modules to access the LoggerClass as if it were in their own global scope without defining it again and again in each and every module. As an example I would change `console.log` in the `ModuleToBeLoaded` class into this:

```
  /**
   * Initialize newly loaded Module.
   * @method init
   * @return {void} [nothing]
   */
  init() {
    LoggerClass.log('module Loaded');
  }
```

So basically I define Globals in the `MainModule` and I want to access these Globals in the Code of the `ModuleToBeLoaded`. A possible solution could be to change the `constructor` in the `ModuleToBeLaoded`. Like this:

```
  constructor(LoggerClass) {
    // Here I can set LoggerClass internally.
    this.LoggerClass = LoggerClass;
  }

  /**
   * Initialize newly loaded Module.
   * @method init
   * @return {void} [nothing]
   */
  init() {
    this.LoggerClass.log('module Loaded');
  }
```

Which could allow me to instantiate the class like this:

```
// Instatiate Module.
ModuleToLoad = new ModuleToLoad(LoggerClass);
```

Is this the right way, or is there any other solution more preferably?

What I want to achieve is the known pattern `singelton pattern` in ES6. 
For more information take a look at this Wikipage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

---

Sidenote: I'm in a `NodeJS 7.10.0` environment without any 3rd party libraries.

Regards,
Megajin

Comment: Why do you have a constructor and an init method?

Comment: `init()` is to start my module it could be called `start` or anything else. However `constructor` is in the ES6 specification take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Comment: So you want `LoggerClass` to be singleton (Same instance for all Modules to load)?

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't you just use the constructor and remove the init?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly yes. I want to access `LoggerClass` through every module which is going to be loaded without instantiating it again and again in every module.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no. If I drop the init and do all the logic in the `constructor ` it would be the wrong way I guess. Since the `constructor ` is used to build the class variables and properties.

Comment: @Megajin its not wrong to do it that way, unless you require the object to be created after something else.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok, but I can't see the purpose of putting my logic into the `constructor`. Let's say I have multiple stuff to do, which I need to be called independently for example `log` and `addNumber`. If I would put these 2 functions into the `cunstructor` I would lose readability and I would need to do some `if else` stuff to prevent them to run all together when I instantiate the module.

Comment: @Megajin why not? It's just a function. Like everything else.

Comment: @Megajin You seem a bit confused regarding `constructor`. See, unlike `init`, constructor will only ever be called once, while your `init` can be invoked multiple times. So unless you need a way to `reset` certain properties of the object to their initial state, there is no point to having a separate `init`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes you are right it is a function like everything else. But as I mentioned it is for the sake of readability. I like strict structures where the logic is seperated. I should point out that there are other methods in my real code which need to be invoked multiple times. This was just an example.

Comment: Yeah. No problem. Going from the examples it seemed like an empty function which didn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I know my bad there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LoggerClass.js** this is how you make singletons (always same instance)

```
let instance;
module.exports = function () {
  if (!instance) {
    instance = new LoggerClass();
  }
  return instance;
}

class LoggerClass {
  constructor() {
    this.instanceData = Date.now();
  }
  log() {
    console.log(`logging secret instance: ${this.instanceData}`);
  }
}
```

**LoadModules.js**

```
const getLoggerClass = require('./LoggerClass');

module.exports = class LoadModules {
  constructor(moduleName) {
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
  }

  init() {
    const path = require('path');
    // changed the require statement, to make it simpler
    let ModuleToLoad = require(path.join(__dirname, this.moduleName + '.js'));
    ModuleToLoad = new ModuleToLoad(getLoggerClass());
    ModuleToLoad.init();
  }
}
```

**ModuleToLoad.js**

```
module.exports = class ModuleToBeLoaded {
  constructor(logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }
  init() {
    console.log('ModuleToBeLoaded module Loaded');
    this.logger.log();
  }
};
```

**ModuleToLoad2.js**

```
module.exports = class ModuleToBeLoaded {
  constructor(logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }
  init() {
    console.log('ModuleToBeLoaded2 module Loaded');
    this.logger.log();
  }
};
```

**Demo**

```
> node
> const LoadModules = require('./LoadModules');
> var load = new LoadModules('ModuleToLoad');
> var load2 = new LoadModules('ModuleToLoad2');

> load.init();
ModuleToBeLoaded module Loaded
logging secret instance: 1495528699144
> load2.init();
ModuleToBeLoaded2 module Loaded
logging secret instance: 1495528699144
```

As you can notice, the instance is the same, according to `this.instanceData` of *LoggerClass*

Removed comments to make code more minimal

Comment: Thanks for your answer since objects are passed by reference in JavaScript my presumption was right ro use the constructor.

Comment: @Megajin well, there is no such thing like `do this way`, it always depends on things you want to achieve, try using constructor, then a method, then you get your signature of writing code

Answer (score 0):

I find it strange that you have a separate `constructor` and `init`. Why not do the initialization in the constructor?

Anyway, it seems like the right approach is indeed to pass your "global" to the constructor or init of the module you want to load.

If you really want it to be a global, you can add it to the `global` namespace.

Comment: I need both since constructor will be invoked once. And I need other functions which are not shown in my example to be invoked multiple times. `init()` was just an example.